# Do mobile internet providers block outgoing SSH?

Tags: ssh, firewall

So spread around the world we have a few pc's that connect to our server over SSH for reverse forwarding. Most of these clients are connected to the internet over some 3G receiver and one of them told me it stopped working once he switched internet provider.

He confirmed that he could visit regular internet services like email and normal websites and when I put a "Hello World!"-website on one of our test servers on port 22 he was also unable to visit that page.

Do mobile internet providers block certain outgoing ports? I've read that sshd can run on multiple ports simoultaneously so I guess this could be solved by opening up another port that has another common use.
So my questions are:

1. Is it heard of that mobile internet providers block certain outgoing ports?
2. What port is probably safe to use instead of 22? (Only 80 and 443 are not an option) So which port is probably never blocked? 25 for email?

Comment: Many mobile carriers use proxy servers. I've heard that some people on some carriers have been successful in circumventing these proxies by using a VPN. If you already have a server setup it might be worthwhile to install openvpn and see how their connections respond to that. In my experience only the most vicious proxies (eg corporate) implement full transparent proxies for encrypted connections and I think you'll find they will easily pass through whatever roadblock the carrier has created. They may also notice a big improvement in latency while on a VPN.

Comment: To clarify on the proxies - typically the carrier installs their own CA certs on 'their' phones so it's anything but obvious to determine if this is the case for a given company/ region. Using nmap you can get s good baseline of their service restrictions. Here's a good wiki article on the issues and common workarounds, including VPNs and ssh tunnels ( which are starting to converge from a capability perspective)

Comment: Back in the day, I've had problems with T-Mobile when trying to SSH.  I heard Verizon was better.  That was before T-Mobile's "Uncarrier" initiative where they started doing many more things right.  Hopefully they're better now.  Another port you might find often allowed is 53 (particularly UDP, which might not help you if you're trying to SSH...  though maybe they end up allowing TCP 53 too.  Then again, maybe they sandbox 53 and redirect to their own servers.)